# Kmodes function Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

Tags: sql, r

I got this error when using a big data set, I cleaned the data and used `Data<-na.omit(Data)` to delete all rows with nulls, it worked and in RStudio I don't get any errors.
When I run the script in SQL as an external script I get the same error as before

```r
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

even though I'm using the same Rscript and dataset is the same.
Has anyone had the same issue and how did you solve it.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean *"when I run the script in SQL"*? Are you running it in SQL Server within a stored-proc using R as the script engine? The error `replacement has length zero` is relatively clear (with a lot of related questions here on SO), though it is not clear to me whether this error is from *your* code or some function. Since we don't know what non-base packages you are using, the search domain to find functions that you might be using is rather large. (There are too many unknowns in this question for me to be able to offer any other advice. Good luck!)

Comment: Hi, yes I run the external R script from a store proc. I have managed to 'fix' this error by changing the data type to as.numeric(data$field).